# Pass additional parameters to emit event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have following scenario:

I have an dropdown component. Whenever you select some propertie it emits the selected value in my case the color with

`this.$emit("setColor", "somecolor")`

In my parent component i listen to this event with `<mycomponent @setColor="setColor" />` and execute an method called `setColor`

This component is actually rendered in a `v-for` and for this i want to pass my index of the current iteration to the `setColor`, how do i do that?

i tried with `@setColor="setColor(i)"` but then my color that i am passing from the child to the parent is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$event` keyword to pass the event payload. So you can call your method like below :

```
@setColor="setColor($event,i)"
```